# How to access substrings in pandas column and store it into new columns?

Tags: python, dataset, pandas, data-cleaning

I'm working on a dataset for building permits. In the dataset there is a column that gives the location (lattitude and longitude) for the building permit. The data in the location column look like this:

```
0    (37.785719256680785, -122.40852313194863)
1     (37.78733980600732, -122.41063199757738)
2      (37.7946573324287, -122.42232562979227)
3     (37.79595867909168, -122.41557405519474)
4     (37.78315261897309, -122.40950883997789)
Name: location, dtype: object
```

As you can see, the data is stored as strings. I wanted to store the lattitude and longitude in two separate columns, so I wrote the following code to accomplish this:

```
df.location = df.location.str.replace('(','')
df.location = df.location.str.replace(')','')


for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.location[i] == np.nan:
        df['lattitude'] = np.nan
    else:
        df['lattitude'] = df.location[i][0:df['location'][i].index(',')]

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.location[i] == np.nan:
        df['longitude'] = np.nan
    else:
        df['longitude'] = df.location[i][0:df['location'][i].index(',')]
```

There is some missing data in the column, 1700 entries to be exact. So in order to avoid a key error, I wrote the if-else statement to fill in the new columns with np.nan anytime the loop would iterate to a missing entry.

When I ran the code, I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-81826748e81c> in <module>()
      7         df['lattitude'] = np.nan
      8     else:
----> 9         df['lattitude'] = df.location[i][0:df['location'][i].index(',')]
     10 
     11 for i in range(len(df)):

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Can anybody spot the error I'm making?

Comment: You need to use integers to index a df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *perhaps* more suited for StackOverflow. I would also use a better/more descriptive title for the question itself; that way others that are facing a similar problem are able to find it.

The reason you are seeing that error is because of the `nan` values, which are of type float. So while most of the rows in `df['location']` contain strings, every row instance of an `nan` in the column is a float, and `str.index()` is not available for floats.

Your check of `if df.location[i] == np.nan:` is pointless, because `np.nan == np.nan` is always `False` due to the very definition of `nan`. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320022/why-in-numpy-nan-nan-is-false-while-nan-in-nan-is-true) on the topic. Because your check fails, the loop enters the `else` block and encounters a float object attempting to invoke a string method.

In my opinion you are using a very complicated approach to get what you want.

Replace your code with this. It should give you what you are looking for. Any `nan` values encountered will be handled by python.

```
df['location']=df['location'].str.replace(" ","").str.strip('(').str.strip(')')
df['latitude']=df['location'].str.split(',').str[0]
df['longitude']=df['location'].str.split(',').str[1]
```

I tested this using the following code segment:

```
df=pd.DataFrame()

df['location']=(
"(37.785719256680785, -122.40852313194863)",
"(37.78733980600732, -122.41063199757738)",
"(37.7946573324287, -122.42232562979227)",
"(37.79595867909168, -122.41557405519474)",
"(37.78315261897309, -122.40950883997789)",
np.nan,
"(37.78615261897309, -122.405550883997789)")

df['location']=df['location'].str.replace(" ", "").str.strip('(').str.strip(')')
df['latitude']=df['location'].str.split(',').str[0]
df['longitude']=df['location'].str.split(',').str[1]

print(df[['latitude','longitude']])
```

This produces the output:

```
             latitude             longitude
0  37.785719256680785   -122.40852313194863
1   37.78733980600732   -122.41063199757738
2    37.7946573324287   -122.42232562979227
3   37.79595867909168   -122.41557405519474
4   37.78315261897309   -122.40950883997789
5                 NaN                   NaN
6   37.78615261897309  -122.405550883997789
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And thank you for the advice you gave in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right from this one, the `df['location'][i]` should be some kind of a `float` and you can't get `index` from the `float` type. Check the type of the `df['location'][i]` with the `isinstance(df['location'][i], float)` you don't need to but just so you can see that it is really `float`. The error tells you everything. Maybe you are expecting string? There is not really much to say.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have figured out what cause the error.

However, I will propose another way to create new columns `latitude` and `longitude` from existing column `location`.

If values in column `location` are string, then

```
t = df.loc[df.location.isnull()]  # keep NaN rows in t for awhile
df.dropna(inplace=True)           # get rid of NaN rows

# create new columns
df['latitude'] = df.location.apply(lambda x: x.strip('()').split(',')[0])
df['longitude'] = df.location.apply(lambda x: x.strip('()').split(',')[1])

# put NaN rows back in their place
df = df.append(t, sort=False).sort_index()
```

But if values in column location are tuple of 2 float numbers, create new columns by this:

```
# create new columns
df['latitude'] = df.location.apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['longitude'] = df.location.apply(lambda x: x[1])
```